# Hosting self-contained deployment of .NET CORE - no dotnet.exe

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core

I have followed (as far as I can tell) all of the instructions located here for a self contained .NET core deployment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis

According to the page, I only need to run this command to get the module installed in IIS

```
DotNetCore.1.0.3_1.1.0-WindowsHosting.exe OPT_INSTALL_LTS_REDIST=0 OPT_INSTALL_FTS_REDIST=0
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mypackage.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

But, the dotnet.exe is no where to be found on my server.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have published your application as a portable application (i.e. one that is trying to using shared runtime) but did not install the runtime. You either need to install the runtime, or you need make changes to your application (project.json/*.csproj really) to make it standalone in which case when publishing it will contain the runtime with it. 
From web.config perspective - when publishing a standalone application the `processPath` is `{application}.exe` instead of `dotnet`